# Continuity of $f(x)=\begin{cases}x, & x \in\Bbb{Q}\\0 & x \in\Bbb{Q}^c\end{cases}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, continuity

I want to prove that the function $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ defined by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x, &  x \in\Bbb{Q}\\0 & x \in\Bbb{Q}^c\end{cases}$$

is not continuous at $x_0\in \Bbb{R},\;x_0\neq 0,$ but do not know how to solve the problem. Please, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Hint: use the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity and the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. What can you tell about an arbitrarily small neighbourhood around $x_0$?

Comment: Easy hint: break it into the cases $x_0\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $x_0\in\mathbb{Q}^c$; in each case, you should be able to find 'nearby' points in the other camp, and thus greater than a relevant epsilon away...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can always find a sequence of rational numbers converging to an irrational number. For example

$$x_n = \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}$$

where $F_n$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ Fibonacci number. We have $$x_n \rightarrow \phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
where $\phi$ is the golden ratio

Therefore, if $f$ was continuous then $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(\phi)$, but $$f(x_n)=x_n, \ \ \ \ \ f(\phi)=0$$
therefore $f$ isn't continous

---

Similarly, you can find a sequence of irrational numbers converging to a rational number, for example $x_n = \sqrt[n]{n} \rightarrow 1$, but on applying $f$ we get $f(\sqrt[n]{n}) = 0$ and $f(1)=1$

Comment: @ junkquill: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

note that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. You can always find a sequence of rational numbers that converge to a irrational number